# What is the proper technique for creating and managing complex data models in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a relational database background, know a bit of Python, and am a complete Django newbie / wannabe. I've been considering doing some projects in Django. One thing I've noticed, however, is that, in Django, you create your data model in code rather than with an ER modeling tool (like ERwin or Embarcadero).

My question is:

Is it possible to import a complex data model (populated or not) into Django and visualize it with an ER diagram?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, django models are indeed a reflection of database. But on the other hand, they are also python classes. You should think in terms of class entities instead of database level design. Many built in fields could also help you simplify the relationship, like with `ManyToManyField` you don't need to care about the intermediate relationship table created underline. You should take a project you think it's complex enough and try with django. That might better answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most valuable features of the Django is its ORM and some `manage.py` commands to help untangle complex data models. If you haven't explored [django_extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) yet, I think it has what you want: `manage.py graph_models` gives you a customizable ER diagram of your models. I use this often when dealing with large databases. I am often required to import a large DB model (from an existing set of databases) and generate almost all of the DB model using the django builtin `manage.py inspectdb > models.py`. And with `graph_models` you can try a variety of layouts and various amounts of detail to help you see the "big picture." Even if the ultimate goal isn't to build a Django webapp, I find these tools helpful in understanding a DB model quickly, especially when you don't have access to the original DB creator(s) or their reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually Django uses a ORM (Object Relational Mapping) which actually is more simple than it looks. What I recommend would (for question 2) is build it in a ER diagram then create the code associated with the Entities for example:

(SQL Looking One)
Person
- Name VARCHAR(50),
- ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

(Python Code)

```
class Person:
    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = 'Neo')
    # Also best part is, you ID is already made
```

This is a simple example and I recommend looking into the Django Docs for Models to get more into it. This link might help:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Isn't the downside to this approach that your documentation and your physical model are not automatically synchronized? So, if you make a change to one, don't you then have to manually make the change to the other?

Comment: True, but there are additional properties which can be use (basically default values and many other). Django is based upon a MVC models so this is actually the approach need to be taken. Usually when you make changes to a Model you must "Migrate" these changes. So it automatically updated (I highly recommend the default parameter as you might get to some problems later down the time which you probably notice)